# How to connect a QML signal with a C++ slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with a `MessageDialog` signal in QML. In my `MessageDialog` I have two buttons for *Yes* and *No*. I want to connect each button with a signal.
Here is my qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

Item{
    MessageDialog {
        signal qmlYesSig(string msg)
        signal qmlNoSig (string msg)
        title: "Send data?"
        icon: StandardIcon.Question
        text: "Do you want to save your data on the online platform?"
        detailedText: "Click Yes "
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No
        Component.onCompleted: visible = true
        onYes: qmlYesSig("From yes")
        onNo: qmlNoSig("From no")
    }
}
```

Here is my slot:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cppSlot(const QString &msg) {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
    }
};
```

And here is how i use this in main:

```
QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("window.qml"));
QObject *item = view.rootObject();
AddData myClass;
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                 &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

view.show();
```

It give me the error:

> C2665: 'QObject::connect': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types

I have try many times but I can't make work QML signal and C++ slots.
Also I have try the example from here [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) and give me the same error.

Can somebody give me an idea how to connect QML signal and C++ slots for a `MessageDialog`?

Comment: Where did you define the signal `qmlSignal`? Not in `QObject *item = view.rootObject();`

Comment: It's first time when i work with signal from qml.I don't really understand what should i do more.When a button is pushed it emit a signal that should be catch in C++, write?

Comment: Still, you can debug your `view.rootObject()` and see that is not your MessageDialog where the signal is defined. So either define it in your root `Item` or get the `MessageDialog` child object in C++ to connect the signal.

Comment: I just checked the Qt Doc, I guess you can use `view.rootObject()->childItems().first()` (that should be your MessageDialog)

Comment: ok, you are right, But first i need to solve the error. The parameters for connect are not matching and i don t understand why.

Comment: Your connect seems ok, I did miss that problem, I guess your `AddData` class  is derived from `QObject` etc?

Comment: should `qmlSignal` be `qmlYesSig`?

Comment: @stefaanv yes that too, But that doesn't explain the compile error, since the signals and slot names are just strings when using the SIGNAL and SLOT macros, so they're evaluated at runtime... weird

Comment: Okay, I tend to use the new connect syntax, so I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: If i make a new clean project, give me other error:  C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'QQuickItem *' to 'QObject *'. Maybe there is the problem

Comment: yes `view.rootObject()` returns `QQuickItem*`, there are just to many errors in the code I guess, so the error OP is getting might be false or some other compiler cache issue after all..

Comment: ok, i will try to fix this. But from your point of view the qml is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your QML file is:

```
Item{
    MessageDialog {
        signal qmlYesSig(string msg)
        signal qmlNoSig (string msg)

        [...]
    }
}
```

And your C++ code is:

```
QObject *item = view.rootObject();
AddData myClass;
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                 &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
```

It means that you are looking for a signal called "qmlSignal" in the root item of your QML file. 
This root item is simply

```
Item{}
```

As you can see, there is no signal called "qmlSignal".

You have to define the signal in the root item and emit it from the message box.

```
Item{
    signal qmlSignal(string msg)

    MessageDialog {
        onYes: parent.qmlSignal("From yes")
        onNo: parent.qmlSignal("From no")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dydil. That work but i have some errors when i use "QObject *item = view.rootObject();" It says : "cannot convert 'QQuickItem*' to 'QObject*' ". do you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: @Adi QQuickItem is a QObject so the problem is probably that you forgot `#include <QQuickItem>`.

Comment: Yes, that was :) Thanks

Comment: You connect the rootObject to the signal. What when Item is a PushButton and you have 2 oder more buttons? Or you have not only buttons, but many other items, that have signals. Do you want to name each signal by the button type? Ok button has okSignal, Canel button has cancelSignal and so on... No! That is not the right way

Comment: The use of `parent` in `parent.qmlSignal` does not seem to work for me: I get `TypeError: Property 'qmlSignal' of object QQuickRootItem(0x83e620) is not a function`. A fix is to assign an `id` to  the top level item, and use it instead of `parent`.

Answer (score 8):

You can expose C++ QObject to QML engine and connecting to the slots of C++ QObject from QML side :

In C++ file :

```
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("object", this); // replace this with appropriate object
```

In Qml :

```
qmlYesSig.connect(object.cppSlot);
```

Comment: A more full example would be appreciated. For example where in the QML do you put the connect code? How can you set the type of connection to be queued connection?

Comment: No idea of how to turn your answer into a workable example.  Could you post a complete working example?

Comment: this has to be done inside a function see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72000637/how-can-i-connect-a-qml-signal-to-a-c-slot-within-the-qml-file/72000871#72000871)