# Qt - Embed an ActiveX Control

Tags: qt, activex, qtquick2, qtwidgets

I am developing a new Qt application and I need to embed in it a third party ActiveX Control; I spent the last days learning about Qt Quick Controls 2.0, but I fear that ActiveX Controls can only be embedded in Qt Widgets applications. Is it right?

It will also be great if you can suggest any tutorial/example about my problem, since the official one seems a little bit too hard for a newbie like me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use Qt Quick (QML) altogether with ActiveX Qt embedded widget
>   in one app?

Short answer: yes.

Details: we need to embed both Qt Quick and ActiveX in their own widget containers.

- Build a widget-based Windows Qt application from the start. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ILvH24PYHg).
- Embed QML UI into widgets with [QWidget::createWindowContainer()](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/) which is one of ways to do so.
- Embed or create an independent [QAxWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxwidget.html) to hold ActiveX control in it.
- The best way to deal with third-party ActiveX is to import its type-library like [Qutlook Example (ActiveQt)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-qutlook-example.html).

P.S. QML is not preventing you from doing ActiveX in Qt but they are two separate type of UI and don't share same window. They can only be both embedded in other Qt widgets. I was developing such hybrid applications with Qt/QML/ActiveX and there is no complete guide to do so. Maybe a bit too many details plus you need to deal with specifics of ActiveX interfaces which is a separate topic.

Comment: just use `QQuickWidget` instead of `QQuickView` + `QWidget::createWindowContainer()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it clarified a lot of things to me! I have just another question at the moment: suppose I have a button in QML and I want to do something in the ActiveX Control when clicked, how can I achieve that? Do I have to "attach" the click signal to a slot inside the Widget Window and then call the ActiveX Control?

Comment: Yes, signal-slot is a generic mechanism and will deliver the message.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758113/how-to-connect-a-qml-signal-with-a-c-slot