# How do I get the objectName of QML elements I click on?

Tags: qt, qml, mouseevent, objectname

I'm new in a rather large QML codebase and I want to know the properties of the QML element I click on when running the application, e.g. objectName.

E.g. the name "button" in this [main.qml](https://gist.github.com/elsamuko/a3fd8c0b5c0e17fa490dbda03aa68ce9).

The equivalent in Qt is `QApplication::widgetAt()` or `QWidget::childAt()` I can call in a QMouseEvent.

I need these to identify QML objects within a mixed Qt/QML application for cucumber-cpp step implementations, where I already have a `Helper::click(QString name)`. I put up an example project here:  https://github.com/elsamuko/qml_demo

Comment: Please provide a minimal example demonstrating the framework in which you'd like an answer

Comment: Visible QML items have a childAt() method and Button inherits Item, so you should be able to call it

Comment: The QML Item's function `childAt` is indeed equivalent to `QWidget::childAt`. But if you have overlapping objects, the docs say it will just return the first child it finds, which might not be the one you're interested in. I'm really questioning why you want this functionality. This feels like it might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @JarMan I updated the description. I need it to identify QML objects for UI testing in a mixed Qt/QML application.

Comment: Well, does the QML `childAt` function do what you want?

Comment: I added a [custom class ClickView](https://github.com/elsamuko/qml_demo/blob/main/clickview.cpp#L16) to dump QQuickItem* where the user clicks, but neither the `childAt`, nor all other children are `Button` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, I can work with.
First I implement `mousePressEvent` from `QQuickView` in a derived class.
Then with `findChildren<QObject*>` on the `QQuickView` object, I can find and debug the QML objects. Strangely, `childAt` and `children` do not list the QML child objects.

```cpp
void ClickView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* ev ) {

    QObjectList children = this->findChildren<QObject*>( QRegularExpression( ".+" ) );

    for( QObject* child : children ) {

        // only search for QML types
        if( !strstr( child->metaObject()->className(), "_QMLTYPE_" ) ) { continue; }

        QVariant vX = child->property( "x" );
        QVariant vY = child->property( "y" );
        QVariant vW = child->property( "width" );
        QVariant vH = child->property( "height" );

        if( vX.isValid() && vY.isValid() && vW.isValid() && vH.isValid() ) {
            QRect rect( vX.toInt(), vY.toInt(), vW.toInt(), vH.toInt() );

            if( rect.contains( ev->pos() ) ) {
                qDebug() << child;
            }
        }
    }

    QQuickView::mousePressEvent( ev );
}
```

The complete project is here:
https://github.com/elsamuko/qml_demo

Comment: Qt not allowing one to easily access elements on the page based on their `id` or `name` is a joke

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work

```
Rectangle {
    id: item
    signal qmlSignal(msg: string)
    objectName: "rectangle"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: item.qmlSignal("rectangle clicked")
        onDoubleClicked: item.qmlSignal("rectangle double clicked")
        onEntered: item.qmlSignal("mouse entered the rectangle")
        onExited: item.qmlSignal("mouse left the rectangle")
    }
}
```

if this does not suit you, then you can send a signal from the QML  and find out the name in the slot

[How to connect a QML signal with a C++ slot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758113/how-to-connect-a-qml-signal-with-a-c-slot)

Comment: That's the other way around, I don't have the name "Button".

Comment: this is the same example from your code `objectName: "button"`

Comment: sorry i changed `Button` to `button`

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan Your code takes an `objectName` and finds a pointer to the object. I think the OP is looking for a way to find the `objectName`.

Comment: This still does not give me information about QML objects I click on. Let's assume, I'm in `QApplication::event()` and receive a `QEvent::MouseButtonPress`. Which QML object is under the mouse position.

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan This still doesn't seem helpful to me, sorry. I updated the description and put up an example here: https://github.com/elsamuko/qml_demo