# How can I connect a QML signal to a C++ slot within the QML file

Tags: c++, qt, qml

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762487/14190718), I can connect qml signal and c++ slot in qml file without QObject::connect in c++ file.

But all I got is an error `Expected token ':'` in

```
Window {
    signal sizeChange(int y, int width, int height)
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    height: 1080

    sizeChange.connect(cefWindow.resizeCEFWindow)
                      ^
                      | Expected token ':'
}
```

Comment: This needs to be done inside a function! So for example: `Component.onCompleted: sizeChange.connect(...)`

Comment: The best way in such case is following the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple different ways you could do it. You could put your code in a function as @Amfasis mentioned:

```
Window {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        sizeChange.connect(cefWindow.resizeCEFWindow)
    }
}
```

Or you could just directly call your C++ slot from a signal handler, like this:

```
onSizeChange: {
    cefWindow.resizeCEFWindow()
}
```

I usually prefer the second method myself.